# Import Curves via NPGSQL

Tags: postgis

I'm importing geometries from Oracle to Postgis using NpgsqlBinaryImporter. In case of **CurvePolygons** and **CircularStrings** I get the error

> Geometry type not recognized. GeometryCode: 963

Directly in Postgis with `ST_GeomFromEWKT` the import works fine.

Is there no geometrytype for curves in NPGSQL?